# Foreign Key Constraint Issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Having issues declaring a FK in Oracle 9i. I've looked at a number of examples here on SO and in some online docs (e.g. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) without any real luck; trying a similar syntax to that in the link generates the same error:

```
Error at Command Line:19 Column:4
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here
02253. 00000 -  "constraint specification not allowed here"
*Cause:    Constraint specification is not allowed here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the constraint specification from the statement.
```

An excerpt of the SQL itself is as below. "Line 19" refers to the line starting with `CONSTRAINT`

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
flight_no varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
airplane_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT flight_airplane_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (airplane_id) REFERENCES Airplane (airplane_id)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
dept_date date NOT NULL,
...
```

Alternatively, trying it without the `CONSTRAINT` keyword generates an error about a right parenthesis that I can't seem to see is missing.

PS: I understand ON UPDATE RESTRICT is the default behaviour in Oracle, but I prefer to be explicit wherever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, in Oracle, there is no `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` or `ON DELETE RESTRICT` option.  Those appear to be valid in other database engines but they aren't present in the [constraint syntax diagram](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC) and do not appear to be valid.  There is an `ON DELETE` clause but the only two valid options are `CASCADE` or `SET NULL`.  There is no `ON UPDATE` clause.

If we add a comma at the end of the `airplane_id` definition before the constriant definition and remove the two invalid clauses, your DDL should be valid

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
  flight_no varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
  airplane_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT flight_airplane_id_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (airplane_id) REFERENCES Airplane (airplane_id),
  dept_date date NOT NULL,
  <<more columns>>
);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was referencing other documentation (such as http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_on_delete_restrict_on_delete_no_action_tips.htm) but missed the part where `RESTRICT` was not a valid argument. It seems `NO ACTION` is, however I still get thrown an error when attempting to use that. In short, I want to ensure nothing can be deleted if a child exists.

I assume `ON DELETE CASCADE` is the default behaviour when not explicitly specifying it as part of the constraint?

Comment: @elithrar - If you specify no `ON DELETE` clause, the default prevents a parent row from being deleted if a child row exists.  `ON DELETE SET NULL` sets the child's parent key to `NULL` if the parent is deleted creating an orphan.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` deletes the child record entirely if the parent is deleted.  The only way to get the default behavior is to omit the `ON DELETE` clause-- it does not appear that `ON DELETE NO ACTION` is valid syntax.

Comment: That clears it up. I'm much more familiar with Postgres so some of the Oracle peculiarities get me. Seems that the default behavior is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Put your constraint at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
    flight_no varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    airplane_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    dept_date date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT flight_airplane_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (airplane_id) REFERENCES Airplane  (airplane_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Thanks - did try that but was spitting out a nonsensical error that I couldn't pin down/correct:

    `Error at Command Line:11 Column:11
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Which refers to this line:

`CONSTRAINT flight_airplane_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (airplane_id) REFERENCES Airplane (airplane_id)
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,`