# correcting errors in sql code

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to this website, i hope that i ask the question the right way

```
-- Create a Database table to represent the "FACT" entity. 
CREATE TABLE FACT 
  ( 
     Time_id           DATE NOT NULL, 
     Area_id           INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Reported_crime_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Crime_status      VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
     no_of_crime       INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Max_crime         INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Avg_crime         INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Min_crime         INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     date_reported     DATE NOT NULL, 
     -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "FACT". 
     -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data. 
     CONSTRAINT pk_fact PRIMARY KEY (Time_id, Area_id, Reported_crime_id, 
     Crime_status) 
  ); 

-- Create a Database table to represent the "Crime_Dim" entity. 
CREATE TABLE Crime_Dim 
  ( 
     REPORTED_CRIME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     CRIME_TYPE_Desc   VARCHAR(50), 
     DATE_REPORTED     DATE NOT NULL, 
     Crime_type_id     INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Crime_Dim". 
     -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data. 
     CONSTRAINT pk_crime_dim PRIMARY KEY (REPORTED_CRIME_ID) 
  ); 

-- Create a Database table to represent the "Location_Dim" entity. 
CREATE TABLE Location_Dim 
  ( 
     AREA_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     AREA_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     Area_code INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Force_id  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Location_Dim". 
     -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data. 
     CONSTRAINT pk_location_dim PRIMARY KEY (AREA_ID) 
  ); 

-- Create a Database table to represent the "Time_Dim" entity. 
CREATE TABLE Time_Dim 
  ( 
     Time_id  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     day_id   INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Month_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Year     INTEGER, 
     -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Time_Dim". 
     -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data. 
     CONSTRAINT pk_time_dim PRIMARY KEY (Time_id) 
  ); 

-- Create a Database table to represent the "Reported_crime_dim" entity. 
CREATE TABLE Reported_crime_dim 
  ( 
     Crime_status  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     Date_reported DATE NOT NULL, 
     -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Reported_crime_dim". 
     -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data. 
     CONSTRAINT pk_reported_crime_dim PRIMARY KEY (Crime_status) 
  ); 


-- i.e. tables may be referenced before they have been created.  This method is therefore safer.
-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "FACT_Time_Dim" relationship 
-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "FACT" 
-- correctly references the primary key of table "Time_Dim" 
ALTER TABLE FACT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_fact_to_time_dim FOREIGN KEY(Time_id) REFERENCES Time_Dim( 
  Time_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT; 

-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "FACT_Location_Dim" relationship
-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "FACT" 
-- correctly references the primary key of table "Location_Dim" 
ALTER TABLE FACT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk2_fact_to_location_dim FOREIGN KEY(AREA_ID) REFERENCES 
  Location_Dim(AREA_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT; 

-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "FACT_Crime_Dim" relationship
-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "FACT" 
-- correctly references the primary key of table "Crime_Dim" 
ALTER TABLE FACT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk3_fact_to_crime_dim FOREIGN KEY(REPORTED_CRIME_ID) REFERENCES 
  Crime_Dim(REPORTED_CRIME_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT; 

-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "FACT_Reported_crime_dim" relationship
-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "FACT" 
-- correctly references the primary key of table "Reported_crime_dim" 
ALTER TABLE FACT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk4_fact_to_reported_crime_dim FOREIGN KEY(Crime_status) 
  REFERENCES Reported_crime_dim(Crime_status) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE 
  RESTRICT; 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- End of DDL file auto-generation 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

​
Could someone help me in correcting the errors in the sql code above? when i run the code as mentioned at the last few codes i need to create constraint to prevent Foreign keys in the Fact table and relate them back to their original table if i have got this right... 
could someone correct the code and let me know plz

Comment: Oh. My. Wall. Of. Code.

Comment: What are the errors you got ? Can you show us those errors ?

Comment: More specifically, what do you want the code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: 0.01 ALTER TABLE FACT ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_FACT_to_Time_Dim FOREIGN ORA-00905: missing keyword  -
7 0.01 ALTER TABLE FACT ADD CONSTRAINT fk2_FACT_to_Location_Dim FOR ORA-00905: missing keyword  -
8 0.01 ALTER TABLE FACT ADD CONSTRAINT fk3_FACT_to_Crime_Dim FOREIG ORA-00905: missing keyword  -
9 0.01 ALTER TABLE FACT ADD CONSTRAINT fk4_FACT_to_Reported_crime_d ORA-00905: missing keyword   this is the error i get when i run the code. does this mean anything?

Comment: thank you for the reply guys. Dan i want to run the code to create four tables and a FACT table. i am trying to remove/ correct the errors in the code. notice the code created usng forward engineering in Qsee

Comment: thank u for letting me know Marc, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996229/foreign-key-constraint-issue-in-oracle), you have to remove `ON DELETE RESTRICT` and `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`. 
There's no such option in Oracle.