# ORA-00906 error , missing parentheses

Tags: sql, oracle, get, oracle10g

i'v a problem with this query :

```
alter table COMMANDER
add foreign key FK_COMMANDE_LIEN_93_CLINET (IDCL)
   references CLINET (IDCL) on update restrict on delete restrict;
```

I receive an error ORA-00906 , any solutions ?

Comment: Where did you copy this syntax from ?

Comment: Am using PowerAmc and that software generate the sql query from the conceptual data model .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE COMMANDER
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COMMANDE_LIEN_93_CLINET
FOREIGN KEY (IDCL)
REFERENCES CLINET(IDCL);
```

In reference to the ON UPDATE/DELETE RESTRICT, see: [Foreign Key Constraint Issue in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996229/foreign-key-constraint-issue-in-oracle)

Comment: Now i got the ORA-00905 error , on the last line ( on update restrict ... )

Comment: Thankies that's really helpful , i was not know that there is no ON UPDATE RESTRICT or ON DELETE RESTRICT option.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
ALTER TABLE commander
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_commande_lien_93_clinet  FOREIGN KEY (idcl)
REFERENCES clinet (idcl) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Now i got the ORA-00905 error , on the last line ( on update restrict ... )